# How to add colored points with white shadow border in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs

trying to add colored points with white shadow border in React chart.js Version: 2.7.2 but no luck please any help.

what I have now

[image]

my code:

```
   <div  style={{height: '200px', width: '400px', position: 'relative'}} className={'line-chart'}>


                <Line data={{
                    labels: ["May 09", "May 15", "May 29", "Jun 03"],
                    datasets: [{
                        data: [
                            {
                                x: "May 09",
                                y: 80,
                            },
                            {
                                x: "May 15",
                                y: 98
                            },
                            {
                                x: "May 29",
                                y: 90
                            },
                            {
                                x: "Jun 03",
                                y: 110
                            },
                        ],
                        pointBackgroundColor: ["#f7aa2e", "#05b9af", "#ee734e", "#ee734e"],
                        pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.2)',
                        pointBorderWidth: 3,
                        pointRadius: 4,
                        pointHoverRadius: 5,
                        lineTension: 0,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        fill: false,
                    }]
                }}
                      options={{
                          legend: {
                              display: false
                          },
                          responsive: true,
                          // maintainAspectRatio: false,
                          scales: {
                              yAxes: [{
                                  display: false
                              }],
                              xAxes: [{
                                  type: 'category',
                                  gridLines: {
                                      display: false
                                  }
                              }]
                          },
                          tooltips: {
                              enabled: false,
                          }

                      }}
                />

            </div>
```

what I'm trying to do

[image]

this chart with chart.js Version: 2.6.0 is the chart css different between this two versions?

Comment: Hi Fadi, did you find a way around it, I am trying to do the same thing?

Comment: @AbhishekSoni as i remember no

Comment: Okay, no problem, I have custom-drawn it on canvas now, and thanks a lot for replying, means a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove border from point then you add `pointBorderWidth: 0,` and just remove `pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.2)',`

Comment: hi, i don't want to remove the border i need a white border and around it a black shadow like in the second image